# How to use Ajax to make a request and update the data within a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have table that is filled with data from an instance variable. How would I use Ajax to make a request and update the data within the table to reflect the new data for the instance variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general answer, Rails comes with some great helpers to make working with Ajax quite simple. I suggest [reading up on the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) for in depth coverage on this topic.

To trigger a specific controller action via Ajax, you can do something like this:

Somewhere in your table view, where appropriate:

```
<%= button_to "Do Something!", [:your_action, @example], remote: true %>
```

Then in your target controller:

```
def your_action
  #Do whatever you wish here

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @example, notice: 'Action successfully performed.' }
    format.js {}
  end
end
```

The `format.js` in the respond_to block allows the controller to respond to the Ajax request. You can then create a respective `app/views/examples/your_action.js.erb` file that generates the JS that will be sent/executed on the client side:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @example) %>").appendTo("#your-table-element");
```